# Cannot use gem elisehuard-google_translate

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use this gem https://github.com/elisehuard/google_translate

After successfully installing it I can include it in my code. However I cannot instantiate its module classes.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
#translate.rb

require 'google_translate'

translator = Translator.new("en","fr")
```

And here is the error that I get:

```
$ ruby translate.rb
translate.rb:4:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Translator (NameError)
```

After adding the namespace, I am getting this error:

/gems/elisehuard-google_translate-0.0.3/lib/google_translate/api_call.rb:14:in `google_api_call': Please use Translate v2.  See http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html (GoogleTranslate::GoogleException)

Thanks

Comment: The docs say "include module GoogleTranslate (or use it as namespace, as required)" so you either `include GoogleTranslate` in your class or you say `GoogleTranslator::Translator.new(...)`.

Comment: Thanks. Its been a while i did not works with ruby. You can post your comment as answer so that I accept it.